# Handling WebView having loaded?

Tags: objective-c, macos, webview

I'm writing a browser application for Mac to match my Windows one. I have a WebView on my window and so far I have a working browser. However, I need to run a method I've written when the WebView finishes loading a page. Is there a way to do this? If not, how can I work around that? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can call your method in the `webView:didFinishLoadForFrame:` delegate call that is in the [WebFrameLoadDelegate](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Webkit/Protocols/WebFrameLoadDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSObject/webView%3adidFinishLoadForFrame%3a).

Comment: Thanks! That was exactly what I wanted to do!